# Basic "Click to Show" button with "Show All" Option

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to do something super basic - I've looked around and all other answers are overly complex. I just want to show an answer on click, and have an option to show all on click.

```js
$('.quiz_show_answer').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var answer = $(this).attr('answer');
  var parent = $(this).parent();

  $(this).hide();
  $(parent).append(answer);
});
$('.quiz_show_all').each(function(index) {
  $(this).click(function() {
    var answers = $('.quiz_show_answer');
    var answer = $('.quiz_show_answer').attr('answer');
    var parents = $(answers).parent();

    $(answers).hide();
    $(parents).append(answer);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:;" class="quiz_answer quiz_show_all pull-right" title="Click to Show All Answers">Show All</a>
<br>
<div><a href="javascript:;" class="quiz_answer quiz_show_answer quiz_show_answer_1" answer="one">Answer</a></div>
<div><a href="javascript:;" class="quiz_answer quiz_show_answer quiz_show_answer_2" answer="two">Answer</a></div>
<div><a href="javascript:;" class="quiz_answer quiz_show_answer quiz_show_answer_3" answer="three">Answer</a></div>
<div><a href="javascript:;" class="quiz_answer quiz_show_answer quiz_show_answer_4" answer="four">Answer</a></div>
<div><a href="javascript:;" class="quiz_answer quiz_show_answer quiz_show_answer_5" answer="five">Answer</a></div>
<div><a href="javascript:;" class="quiz_answer quiz_show_answer quiz_show_answer_6" answer="six">Answer</a></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare two event handlers in this way:

- when you click on `.quiz_show_answer`: you should hide the current element and replace the parent text with the current answer;
- when you click on `.quiz_show_all`: you should hide the current element and trigger a click on every `.quiz_show_answer`.

```js
$('.quiz_show_answer').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).hide().parent().text($(this).attr('answer'));
});
$('.quiz_show_all').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).hide();
  $('.quiz_show_answer').trigger('click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="quiz_answer quiz_show_all pull-right" title="Click to Show All Answers">Show All</a>
<br>
<div><a href="#" class="quiz_answer quiz_show_answer quiz_show_answer_1" answer="one">Answer</a></div>
<div><a href="#" class="quiz_answer quiz_show_answer quiz_show_answer_2" answer="two">Answer</a></div>
<div><a href="#" class="quiz_answer quiz_show_answer quiz_show_answer_3" answer="three">Answer</a></div>
<div><a href="#" class="quiz_answer quiz_show_answer quiz_show_answer_4" answer="four">Answer</a></div>
<div><a href="#" class="quiz_answer quiz_show_answer quiz_show_answer_5" answer="five">Answer</a></div>
<div><a href="#" class="quiz_answer quiz_show_answer quiz_show_answer_6" answer="six">Answer</a></div>
```